# leaflet.js gdpr compliant integration

Tags: javascript, leaflet

is there a possibility to use leaflet.js in a gdpr compliant way? 
the reason is, all/most api calls to map servers which leaflet.js does, creates 3rd party cookies. these cookies are not alloed by the gdpr law before the visitor makes an opt in decission to use the maps api (osm, gmaps,...).
so my question is, does leaflet.js has a kind of property or way to prevent these api calls until a specific event (for instance an opt-in by user) gets triggered by js? for instance similar to google analytics approach with ga-disable-UA-XXXXXX-X?

Comment: Use your own tile server.

Comment: using an on tile server is not possible in this scenario.

Comment: Then this is a question about tile/geocoding services, and not about Leaflet itself.

Comment: yes in some case. tile/geoconding should be prevented until the user made an opt-in. should i change anything in my text/headline?

Comment: The obvious answer is gonna be "don't add any tilelayers to the map before some event happens", which falls on your part. Perhaps you might want to put examples of the tile/geocoding services you're worried about, and focus on that.

Comment: Could you already find a solution for this? Maybe something like embetty could be used to wrap leaflet: https://github.com/heiseonline/embetty/issues/403

Comment: Another library that might be helpful: https://github.com/orestbida/iframemanager    https://github.com/orestbida/iframemanager/issues/19

Comment: yes i solved it, as @IvanSanchez mentioned